# SonarQube does not support parallel execution - How to use in continuous pipeline

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube does not support parallel execution as parallel execution is failing with:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: The project is already been analysing
```

I am using `SonarQube v4.3.3` for code inspection.

Now my hudson jobs are running in parallel and due to this restriction I am not able to add sonar analysis to my Hudson job.

Please suggest how can I use SonarQube with hudson in a continuous pipeline using SonarQube.

Answer (score 3):

SonarQube 4.x does support parallel analysis of different projects, but not parallel analysis of the same project. This is a technical constraint to avoid conflicts when persisting analysis into the shared database.

SonarQube 5.2 introduces a major architecture change. Analyzers (launched by your Hudson job) are no more connected to database. They generate and send to server a report that contains only raw data, basically sources and issues. Computation of measures, validation of Quality gate and persistence are done asynchronously on server. In your case that allows analyzers to be executed in parallel, even on the same project, but they can't directly verify Quality gate. For that you should implement a kind of listener on web services to get the gate status when report is processed. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build for more details. Note also that version 2 of the build breaker plugin implements this solution directly in the analyzer (see https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker)

Comment: Analysis is for the same project but for different version.

Example: 
Run (1) is for Git repository A for commit 'AA'
Run (2) is for the same project but different commit say 'BB'

Comment: This case is not supported yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Please let me know then what is the best practice to include Sonarqube into continuous pipeline in Hudson.

My requirement is just to run sonar analysis for every commit into my git repository and if the the Quality gates are not passed then fail the hudson build. Please note that concurrent builds are enabled for my hudson build job.

Comment: My initial answer was about the version 4.3 that you use. I completed with version 5.x.

Comment: Please let me know which is the minimum supported SonarQube version which support concurrent analysis of the same project but with different version.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: SQ 5.2 introduces the change. Still depending on your environment I suggest to wait for the next 5.x Long Term Support version.

Comment: Please let me know if the concurrent run will work, if I use the preview ode of analysis (sonar.analysis.mode=preview) in SonarQube v4.3.3.

Comment: yes, parallel executions in preview mode are supposed to be supported in 4.x.